# Need js method of triggering button

Tags: javascript, navigation, touch, swipe

Is there a way to trigger a button when user swipes across a touch-friendly device?  I'm looking to allow the user to view my website on a tablet and swipe left and right between articles on a page that normally have arrows to press with a mouseclick.  Is there a way to allow for this additional form of navigation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[jQuery Mobile](http://api.jquerymobile.com/swipe/) or [TouchSwipe](http://www.awwwards.com/touchswipe-a-jquery-plugin-for-touch-and-gesture-based-interaction.html) have swipe events which you could use to call the same function the button is calling.

Comment: Could I use $("#id_of_button").click(); with it?

Comment: just remembered I needed to add the "@" so you will be notified....  It works perfectly. Thank you!